# gstreamer and gdkpixbuf sink eats huge amounts of memory - possible leak

Tags: memory-leaks, gstreamer, gdk, gdkpixbuf

I have a simple program which reads GdkPixbufs from a video stream frame by frame.
The problem is that the memory usage grows at about 300-400MB per second! That way my 8GB RAM are used up in no time.
Valgrind / Cachegrind didn't point me anywhere so maybe it's a bug in gstreamer?

```
    // compiled with:
    //  g++ -std=c++11 `pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0 gdk-pixbuf-2.0` test_c.cpp -o test `pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0 gdk-pixbuf-2.0`
    // usage:
    //  ./test -i video_file.mpg # MUST BE SAME FORMAT AS TEST IMAGE DATA PROVIDED IN main.cpp BELOW!!!

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <memory.h>
    #include <vector>
    #include <gst/gst.h>
    #include <gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h>
    #include <gst/controller/controller.h>  // GstPlugin
    #include <glib.h>

    #define APP_NAME    "test"

    typedef struct
    {
        int                                 nWidth;
        int                                 nHeight;
        GdkColorspace               ColorSpace;
        int                                 nBitsPerChannel;
        int                                 nChannels;
        gboolean                        bHasAlpha;
        int                                 nRowStride;
        gsize                               nByteLength;
        guchar                          *pPixels;
    } tSImage;

    typedef std::vector<tSImage *> tImagesList;

    GMainLoop                       *g_pMainLoop;
    gchar                               *g_pszInFile;
    GstElement                  *g_pPipeline;
    GstElement                  *g_pElementVideoSink;
    tImagesList                 g_ImagesList;

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void EatLotsOfMemory(tSImage *pFrame)
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        // access to pixel buffers leads to huge memory consumption!
        for(tImagesList::const_iterator iImage=g_ImagesList.begin(); iImage!=g_ImagesList.end(); iImage++)
        {
            unsigned long test = 0;
            for(int nPos=0; nPos < pFrame->nHeight * pFrame->nRowStride; nPos++)
            {
                if(pFrame->pPixels[nPos] == (*iImage)->pPixels[nPos])
                {
                    test++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    bool ParsePixBufMessage(const GValue *val)
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        gint64 pos;
        if(gst_element_query_position(g_pPipeline, GST_FORMAT_TIME, &pos))
            g_print("Time: %" GST_TIME_FORMAT " \r", GST_TIME_ARGS(pos));

        GdkPixbuf *pPixBuf = GDK_PIXBUF(g_value_dup_object(val));

        tSImage Image;
        Image.ColorSpace                = gdk_pixbuf_get_colorspace(pPixBuf);
        Image.nChannels                 = gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels(pPixBuf);
        Image.bHasAlpha                 = gdk_pixbuf_get_has_alpha(pPixBuf);
        Image.nBitsPerChannel       = gdk_pixbuf_get_bits_per_sample(pPixBuf);
        Image.nWidth                        = gdk_pixbuf_get_width(pPixBuf);
        Image.nHeight                       = gdk_pixbuf_get_height(pPixBuf);
        Image.nRowStride                = gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride(pPixBuf);
        Image.nByteLength               = gdk_pixbuf_get_byte_length(pPixBuf);
        Image.pPixels                       = gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels(pPixBuf);

        EatLotsOfMemory(&Image);

        g_object_unref(pPixBuf);
        return true;
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    static gboolean BusCallback(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, gpointer data)
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        switch(GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg))
        {
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
                g_print("End of stream\n");
                g_main_loop_quit(g_pMainLoop);
            break;

            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
            {
                gchar  *debug;
                GError *error;

                gst_message_parse_error(msg, &error, &debug);
                g_free(debug);

                g_printerr("Error: %s\n", error->message);
                g_error_free(error);

                g_main_loop_quit(g_pMainLoop);
            }
            break;

            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            case GST_MESSAGE_ELEMENT:
            {
                if(GST_MESSAGE_SRC(msg) != GST_OBJECT_CAST(g_pElementVideoSink))
                    break;
                const GstStructure *pMsgStructure = gst_message_get_structure(msg);
                if(!gst_structure_has_name(pMsgStructure, "preroll-pixbuf") && !gst_structure_has_name (pMsgStructure, "pixbuf"))
                    break;

                const GValue *val = gst_structure_get_value(pMsgStructure, "pixbuf");
                if(val != NULL)
                    if(!ParsePixBufMessage(val))
                        g_main_loop_quit(g_pMainLoop);
            }
            break;

            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            default:
    //          g_print("msg %u: \"%s\"\n", GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg), GST_MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME(msg));
            break;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    static void on_decoder_pad_added(GstElement *element, GstPad *pPad, gpointer data)
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        GstElement *decoder = (GstElement *) data;

        GstCaps *pCaps = gst_pad_get_current_caps(pPad);

        GstStructure *pCapsStructure = gst_caps_get_structure(pCaps, 0);
        if(pCapsStructure != NULL)
        {
            const gchar *pszStructName = gst_structure_get_name(pCapsStructure);
            if(g_str_has_prefix(pszStructName, "video"))
            {
                GstPad *pSinkpad = gst_element_get_static_pad(decoder, "sink");
                if(pSinkpad != NULL)
                {
                    GstPadLinkReturn Ret = gst_pad_link(pPad, pSinkpad);
                    if(Ret != GST_PAD_LINK_OK)
                        g_print("failed to link pad! (%d)", Ret);
                    gst_object_unref(pSinkpad);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void Decode(gchar *pszFile)
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        g_pMainLoop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

        g_pPipeline                                                 = gst_pipeline_new("pipeline");
        GstBin          *pBin                                       = GST_BIN(g_pPipeline);

        GstElement  *pElementSource                 = gst_element_factory_make("filesrc", "file-source");
        GstElement  *pElementDecoder                = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin", "decoder");
        GstElement  *pElementConvert                = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "convert");  // "autovideoconvert" ?
        g_pElementVideoSink                                 = gst_element_factory_make("gdkpixbufsink", "pixbufsink");  // "imagefreeze" ? "autovideosink" ?
    //  g_pElementVideoSink                                 = gst_element_factory_make("fakesink", "fakesink"); // test

        if(pElementSource == NULL || pElementDecoder == NULL || pElementConvert == NULL || g_pElementVideoSink == NULL)
        {
            g_print("Failed to create elements\n");
            return;
        }

        // configure elements
        g_object_set(G_OBJECT(pElementSource),          "location", pszFile,    NULL);
        g_object_set(G_OBJECT(g_pElementVideoSink), "qos",          FALSE,      "max-lateness", (gint64) - 1, "sync", false, "async", false, NULL);

        // set up pipeline
        gst_bin_add(pBin, pElementSource);

        // add elements to pipeline
        gst_bin_add_many(pBin, pElementDecoder, pElementConvert, g_pElementVideoSink, NULL);

        // link the elements together
        gboolean bOK;
        bOK = gst_element_link(pElementSource, pElementDecoder);
        bOK &= gst_element_link(pElementConvert, g_pElementVideoSink);
        if(!bOK)
        {
            g_print("Failed to link elements\n");
            return;
        }

        // link decoder's video-stream pad dynamically
        g_signal_connect(pElementDecoder, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(on_decoder_pad_added), pElementConvert);

        // add message handler
        GstBus *pBus = gst_element_get_bus(g_pPipeline);
        guint bus_watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch(pBus, BusCallback, NULL /* app data */);

        // set the pipeline to "playing" state
        gst_element_set_state(g_pPipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

        // iterate
        g_main_loop_run(g_pMainLoop);

        // out of the main loop, clean up nicely
        gst_element_set_state(g_pPipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

        gst_object_unref(pBus);
        gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(g_pPipeline));
        g_source_remove(bus_watch_id);
        g_main_loop_unref(g_pMainLoop);
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // main
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    bool ParseOptions(int argc, char *argv[])
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        GError                  *err            = NULL;
        GOptionContext  *ctx;
        GOptionEntry        entries[] =
        {
            { "input",      'i', G_OPTION_FLAG_FILENAME,    G_OPTION_ARG_FILENAME,              &g_pszInFile,       "input video file",                                     NULL },
            { NULL }
        };

        ctx = g_option_context_new("- " APP_NAME);
        g_option_context_add_main_entries(ctx, entries, NULL);
        g_option_context_add_group(ctx, gst_init_get_option_group());
        if(!g_option_context_parse(ctx, &argc, &argv, &err))
        {
            g_print("Failed to initialize: %s\n", err->message);
            g_error_free(err);
            g_option_context_free(ctx);
            return false;
        }

        if(g_pszInFile == NULL)
        {
            g_print("%s", g_option_context_get_help(ctx, TRUE, NULL));
            g_option_context_free(ctx);
            return false;
        }
        g_option_context_free(ctx);

        return true;
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        gst_init(&argc, &argv); // must be called here

        if(!ParseOptions(argc, argv))
            return EXIT_FAILURE;

        // !!! test image data - must match video input format !!!
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            tSImage *pImage = new tSImage();
            pImage->nWidth = 720;
            pImage->nHeight = 576;
            pImage->ColorSpace = GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB;
            pImage->nBitsPerChannel = 8;
            pImage->nChannels = 3;
            pImage->bHasAlpha = false;
            pImage->nRowStride = pImage->nWidth * pImage->nChannels;
            pImage->nByteLength = 0;
            pImage->pPixels = new guchar[pImage->nHeight * pImage->nRowStride];
            memset(pImage->pPixels, (unsigned char) rand(), pImage->nHeight * pImage->nRowStride);

            g_ImagesList.push_back(pImage);
        }

        Decode(g_pszInFile);

        // clear images list
        for(tImagesList::iterator iImage=g_ImagesList.begin(); iImage!=g_ImagesList.end(); iImage++)
        {
            if((*iImage)->pPixels != NULL)
                delete [] (*iImage)->pPixels;
            delete (*iImage);
        }
        g_ImagesList.clear();

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: Is that behaviour specific to the gdkpixbuf sink or would it reproduce if you replace it with e.g. fakesink in your application ?

Answer (score 0):

Running the application with --gst-debug-level=5 may help you spotting allocation and finalization of GST_BUFFER objects. It may also reveal when messages posted on buses are actually consumed. I suspect you have something here that accumulates information and never release it, making the virtual image of your program grow again and again, but everything still has references so valgrind won't find any true leak.

Pay specific attention to buses. They tend to relay a *lot* of information and if left unmanaged, they will hold this information until someone claims it... or unless flushed.